# Can't instantiate generic CustomEvent in TypeScript 2.7.2

Tags: typescript, typescript2.7

I'm using TypeScript 2.7.2 SDK in Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.3).

I'm trying to create a class that inherits from `CustomEvent<T>` where T is specified as an interface, so that I can constrain the type of the detail parameter (which would otherwise be `any`).

This is my sample code, which compiles fine:

```
export interface IFileSendingEventDetail {
    formData: FormData;
}

export class FileSendingEvent extends CustomEvent<IFileSendingEventDetail> {
    constructor(formData: FormData, bubbles: boolean = true) {
        super("file-sending", {
            detail: { formData },
            bubbles: bubbles
        });
    }
}
```

However when I try this code:

```
const e = new FileSendingEvent(new FormData());
```

I get this error in the console:

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'CustomEvent': Please use the 'new'
>   operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong - or is there a bug in TypeScript?